# MVC Form which sends mail

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically I have an MVC 3 form which sends a mail to my inbox when someone leaves a message on my site.

For some reason it throws an SmtpException with the message: "Failure sending mail."

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(string name, string email, string message)
    {
        string From = "contactform@******.com";
        string To = "info@******.com";
        string Subject = name;
        string Body = name + " wrote:<br/><br/>" + message;

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(From, To, Subject, Body);
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMPTobj = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.**********.net");

        SMPTobj.EnableSsl = false;
        SMPTobj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("info@*******.com", "*******");

        try
        {
            SMPTobj.Send(Email);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw new Exception();
        }

        return View();
    }
```

Could this be something to do with testing it locally rather than testing it on a server?

Comment: Are you getting this error when you run it locally? On the server? Both? Do you configure your SMTP server in web.config?

Comment: have you tried setting `SMPTobj.EnableSsl = true;` also you need to set the host like in case of gmail `SMPTobj .Host ="smtp.gmail.com";` and specify a port (gmail) `SMPTobj.Port = 587;`

Comment: It happens both locally and on a web server. I get the error "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to set the SmtpClient.Port to your Host email port?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to try not to rethrow a new exception but just use

```
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
      throw;
 }
```

rethrowing an exception resets the stack, so you can't reliably trace the source of the error. In this case (without rethrowing) you can probably see the InnerException and Status properties in visual studio usually this will give you more details on the reason of the failure. (Often isp's block port 25 smtp traffic, in case you are testing locally)

Second you can try to configure all the connection details in web.config rather then hard coded in your application that makes it easier to test changes. See below for an example using gmail:

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="username@gmail.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" userName="username@gmail.com" password="password" enableSsl="true" port="587" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```